# It's appropriate to add col-* to the class form-group in bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

In order to make some form's components for my project, I defined as a default *template* something like this

```
.form-group
    %label.col-*
        (...) 
    %input.col-*
        (...)
```

Now, I realized, that I might need something a little more flexible, I wonder if it's okay to, lets say, extend my partials allowing to add col-* to my form-group, something, like this.

```
.form-group.col-*
    %label.col-*
        ...
    %input.col-*
        ...
```

Thanks

Comment: Sure.  But I don't think you want to apply it to the label and input inside there *and* the form-group.  Then again I don't really know the desired result from your question.

Comment: Hi Casey, well at first I considered that each pair label/input could be placed in form one after another, so I created partials like that. But much later I recieved an design updates that states that eventually a form may have two columns. SO, I did those partial with some params, but not considering that casa, so either I add col-* to .form-groups or I places more wrappers to create the columns, which I don't want to do at first.

Comment: I still don't totally get your requirements, but you can slap the col things on anything, and you can nest them.  http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid